# How to build an docker image for m1 max

Tags: java, spring-boot, docker, apple-m1, apple-silicon

I have an m1 max macbook pro and wanted to convert an docker image I once did on an ubuntu device to arm64. I am not an docker expert why I am trying to do this is because docker desktop currently tells me the following when I start my own docker image:

```
Image may have poor performance or fail if run via emulation and then there is an amd tag
```

The image I am trying to start is a simple jhipster generated spring boot application micro service.

This is the docker file to generate:

```
# [Choice] Java version (use -bullseye variants on local arm64/Apple Silicon): 11, 17, 11-bullseye, 17-bullseye, 11-buster, 17-buster
ARG VARIANT="11"
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/vscode/devcontainers/java:0-${VARIANT}

# [Option] Install Maven
ARG INSTALL_MAVEN="false"
ARG MAVEN_VERSION=""
# [Option] Install Gradle
ARG INSTALL_GRADLE="false"
ARG GRADLE_VERSION=""
RUN if [ "${INSTALL_MAVEN}" = "true" ]; then su vscode -c "umask 0002 && . /usr/local/sdkman/bin/sdkman-init.sh && sdk install maven \"${MAVEN_VERSION}\""; fi \
    && if [ "${INSTALL_GRADLE}" = "true" ]; then su vscode -c "umask 0002 && . /usr/local/sdkman/bin/sdkman-init.sh && sdk install gradle \"${GRADLE_VERSION}\""; fi

# [Choice] Node.js version: none, lts/*, 16, 14, 12, 10
ARG NODE_VERSION="none"
RUN if [ "${NODE_VERSION}" != "none" ]; then su vscode -c "umask 0002 && . /usr/local/share/nvm/nvm.sh && nvm install ${NODE_VERSION} 2>&1"; fi
```

This is how my docker-compose looks like (only service I am interested right now)

```
 product:
    image: product
    environment:
      - _JAVA_OPTIONS=-Xmx512m -Xms256m
      - SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE=dev,api-docs
      - MANAGEMENT_METRICS_EXPORT_PROMETHEUS_ENABLED=true
      - EUREKA_CLIENT_SERVICE_URL_DEFAULTZONE=http://admin:$${jhipster.registry.password}@jhipster-registry:8761/eureka
      - SPRING_CLOUD_CONFIG_URI=http://admin:$${jhipster.registry.password}@jhipster-registry:8761/config
      - JHIPSTER_SLEEP=30
      - JHIPSTER_REGISTRY_PASSWORD=admin
    ports:
      - '8081:8081'
```

I am pretty new to the apple silicon and docker so every help is appreciated

Comment: You've shown us the work you've done, but you haven't shown us where you got stuck after that work. Each Stack Overflow question should be about one narrow, specific technical problem -- if you get stuck in multiple places, each place should result in a different question, and the question should clearly specify the individual problem it's about.

Comment: Technically I am not stuck my images work and are running as containers. Only the warning message from docker docker desktop concerned me, saying performance can be lagging. Like in my post

Comment: Okay, so the code you're showing isn't an attempt to build a native container, but the source for your existing non-native container? That wasn't clear from the question.

Comment: In general, this is mostly a question of the Docker Desktop installation you run -- if it's running an arm64-native Linux VM, then you have a native arm64 Linux for all your Docker containers; if it's running an x86_64-native Linux VM, then you have x86_64 for all your containers. (Maybe new versions support running multiple VMs with and without CPU emulation, but that's a Docker Desktop question).

Comment: That said, reading the high-level docs at https://docs.docker.com/desktop/mac/apple-silicon/, it looks like arm64 is default, and to get x86_64 you'd need a `--platform` argument with the current release. Make sure you're actually running that current release.